# IntelliJ External Libraries Issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libraries

I am very new to IntelliJ IDE.
My issue is that, in my project I am not able to see the Maven libraries added(as in the image- External Libraries). What it shows me is simply the JDK toolkit.

[image: External Libraries]

The thing is that my application is building properly using .mvn clean install command and there are no compilation issues.

I have tried almost all the resolutions provided in the similar topics in Stack Overflow but they did not work for me.

Comment: Which Intellij version are you using? Community or commercial version? And have you imported your project as a maven project.

Comment: yes, I have imported it as a maven project and I am using community version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting the correct url of settings.xml within IntelliJ

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution and Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven

Enter correct settings.xml path in "User settings file"